# Swapping the context between the flows

Tags: botframework

I am try to implement Swapping context between dialog flows .Assume i am in middle of one dialog flow and i wants to move to another functionality or dialog flow with new utterance..Here bot should prompt Do you want to move to another flow ?...However we have implemented Global Message Scorables here.... Please help me any one. Thanks in advance

i am trying to get the result, i am created one more method in core bot and try to check the luis score again and redirect to new dialog flow based on luis score

enter code here

```
var msg = stepContext.Context.Activity.Text;

var recognizerResult=await 
 _services.BasicBotLuisApplication.RecognizeAsync(stepContext.Context, cancellationToken);

var topScoreIntent = recognizerResult?.GetTopScoringIntent();

elseif(topScoreIntent.Value.score>double.Parse(appSettings.Value.LuisScore))
{
 var luisRes = recognizerResult.Properties["luisResult"] as LuisResult;

 return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(CreateDialog), luisRes, 
 cancellationToken);
}
```

it is working normal flows or type any other keywords like help, cancel, stop. but i give it any dialog flow at that time it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this isn't working, as the logic seems sound. But you say that the other interrupts (which I think in latest core-bot sample are specific utterances) are working. Have you tried checking intent in the interrupt function? Here is what I have done with my nodejs bot, hopefully this will help in your case. Instead of checking for utterances, I'm checking intent. Cancel and Help just provide text, but Expedite and Escalate start new dialogs.

```js
    async isTurnInterrupted(dc, luisResults) {
        const topIntent = LuisRecognizer.topIntent(luisResults);
        const topIntentScore = luisResults.intents[topIntent].score;

        // see if there are any conversation interrupts we need to handle
        if (topIntent === CANCEL_INTENT & topIntentScore > 0.6) {
            if (dc.activeDialog) {
                // cancel all active dialog (clean the stack)
                await dc.cancelAllDialogs();
                await dc.context.sendActivity('Ok. I\'ve cancelled our last activity.');
            } else {
                await dc.context.sendActivity('I don\'t have anything to cancel. If you\'re not trying to cancel something, please ask your question again.');
            }
            return true; // this is an interruption
        }

        if (topIntent === HELP_INTENT & topIntentScore > 0.5) {
            await dc.context.sendActivity('Let me try to provide some help.');
            await dc.context.sendActivity('Right now I am trained to help you with order status and tracking. If you are stuck in a conversation, type "Cancel" to start over.');
            return true; // this is an interruption
        }

        if (topIntent === EXPEDITE_INTENT & topIntentScore > 0.5) {
            await dc.beginDialog(INTERRUPT_DIALOG, topIntent);
            return false; // pushing new dialog so not an interruption
        }

        if (topIntent === ESCALATE_INTENT & topIntentScore > 0.5) {
            await dc.beginDialog(INTERRUPT_DIALOG, topIntent);
            return false; // pushing new dialog so not an interruption
        }

        return false; // this is not an interruption
    }
```